# Link html page or jsp page to multiple django apps

Tags: html, django

I am still new to django, and I have spent 2 hours on looking on how to connect html sites and jsp sites to multiple apps. 
For example, I have index.html, calculator.jsp, login.jsp, register.jsp, and 2 other django apps. The index.html can link to 3 jsp sites, and 2 django apps.

The problem is how to run multiple django servers for multiple apps simultaneously. Can sb help me with step by step ?

I think I should use these: uswgi, nginx or django apache. Nevertheless, I get lost while following the API documentation. Also, there is no youtube video that show how to run multiple django  servers.

Comment: Your question is unclear. JSP is Java, not django. And why do you think you need multiple servers?

Comment: I understand JSP is java, and it is server-side. I want to use multiple technologies for my project. The index.html contains a list of links that connect to different apps. For Django apps, for example, I need to run 127.0.0.1:8000 and 127.0.0.1:8123 at the same time

Comment: But why do you need separate servers for the two Django apps at all? Are they using separate databases etc?

Comment: For now, both apps do not use any database. ( I go from simple to complicated problems., so I will deal with multiple database later ). The first app is about weather app, and the second app is about expense tracker. My index.html page contains links that connect to different apps.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way like this: localhost:8080/project/login.jsp. For example, 127.0.0.1:8000/Weather  127.0.0.1:8000/ExpenseTracker

Comment: Well it you want to keep it simple, then run both apps in the same project. As I said, there is no need for separate servers here.

Comment: Hi, I have another question, how to run 2 servers using terminal ? In other words, I want to run django server and node http server, how can I do that ?